# What is Grant Ward's fighting style in Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Here are some examples:

What is Grant Ward's fighting style, if any?

Comment: His fighting style is hydrated.

Comment: @Adamant, what do you mean by "hydrated"?

Comment: It's there a reason why you made a new account to ask this question?

Comment: His fighting style is "hit things and don't get hit."

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yes.... how can I ask a question without an account?

Comment: @DavidW - Hyperkinetic flailing

Comment: I don't know, how many seasons have you watched?

Comment: Up to the 9th episode of season 7

Comment: OK, well then you will understand that his fighting style started out hydrated, before he was briefly dehydrated, than rehydrated, then dehydrated again. Don't confuse this with Bucky Barnes, who started out dehydrated, then got hydrated, and finally was dehydrated again.

Comment: @Luciano Angel: If I'm not mistaken you previously posted a question about Purity's fight style?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Multiple questions, under multiple accounts. I'm not entirely sure why OP keeps creating new ones, but I know some users prefer to use the site that way.

Comment: This might be better asked on the martialarts.se

Comment: I think MartialArts.SE would not accept this type of question. They rejected the OP's previous similar question.

Comment: Yeah really... *intentionally gaming the accounts/rep system* is not a good look.  If you want to participate in StackExchange, set up an account, stick with it, and own your words.  If you can't handle that and need to post as anonymous, [4channel](http://4channel.org/) is specifically for that.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that his fighting style is "take out as many enemies as possible and as quickly as possible". He does not use any special moves, like roundhouse kicks or a 1-Inch Punch, but rather responds and attacks the way anyone would when in those types of situations and under adrenaline. If you are looking for a very specific style, I think this would be most similar to [SPEAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPEAR_System). Ward doesn't appear to have much science behind his moves, so it would not be like SCARS since it is not very sophisticated. And it would not be like LINE or MCMAP, due to the fact that both of those martial arts contains some traditional touches. So in short, Ward simply mows through any and all opponents that are in his reach. He does not have a very specific style, and is an opportunist, as shown by the fact that he does not really attack a specific part but rather whatever is open, and by the fact that he uses whatever he can reach.